# Design a table in a RDB to sales of multiple items, and calculate the value of the sale

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, ddl

I'm designing a DB for a Mock app and I'm having issues conceptualizing the design of the "Sales" Table.

Supposing I have a
CASHIER table with ID as its PK, name and lname

ARTICLE table with ARTICLE_ID as PK, description, price, stock

SALES table with SALE_ID(pk), ARTICLE_ID(FK article), CASHIER_ID(fk for cashier ID), TOTAL_PRICE_OF_SALE , PRICE_OF_UNIT(FK to ARTICLE price) and UNITS_SOLD

how can I design SALES in such a way that several articles can be sold in 1 transaction?
Normalization rules speak against having a column hold several values, so I don't see how I could store all of the article_id that were sold in a transaction inside an array. Calculating the price also seems problematic.

I know that in DML, you can display a PK several times, but as far as I know, in DDL you can't insert a row with a repeated PK, so I don't see how I could achieve something like

```
SALE_ID | ARTICLE_ID | CASHIER_ID | TOTAL_PRICE_OF_SALE | PRICE_OF_UNIT | UNITS_SOLD
   1         1ASB       JOHNDOE1       50.00                  25.00              1
   1         351A       JOHNDOE1       50.00                  10.00              1
   1         JS57       JOHNDOE1       50.00                  15.00              1
```

In DDL.
Notice that TOTAL_PRICE_OF_SALE should also calculate its value on it's own, during insertion time, but I also don't know how to handle the multiplication of price_of_unit * units_sold and then sum all of it into total_price_of_sale.

Comment: What would be the difference between salesItem and article table?

Comment: So I guess this also means salesItem wouldn't have a PK? Or rather, shouldn't need one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `SALE_ITEM` table to link an `ARTICLE` to a `SALE`.

```
CREATE TABLE SALE_ITEM (
    SALE_ITEM_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    SALE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES SALE(SALE_ID),
    ARTICLE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES ARTICLE(ARTICLE_ID),
    QUANTITY INT,
    -- Its usually safer to copy the price into the 'item' table
    -- so that your order history is accurate even when
    -- the price of the article increases
    PRICE DECIMAL(9,2)
)
```

And remove `ARTICLE_ID` from `SALE`. Or you might prefer to call it `SALE_ARTICLE`

BTW when naming tables I recommend choosing to either use plural or singular table names... but don't use a mix as that will be confusing. Hence I have used `SALE` in this example.

Further I wouldn't use all capitals in table names, instead I would use Pascal Case e.g. `SaleItem`

Also don't store the total sale price unless you have a concrete requirement to do so. Its much simpler to query that when you need it - otherwise you typically need to add a trigger on `SALE_ITEM`. An example of the query method:

```
SELECT SUM(SI.Price*SI.Quantity) TotalPrice
FROM SALE S
INNER JOIN SALE_ITEM SI on SI.SALE_ID = S.SALE_ID;
```

Note: `SALE_ITEM` doesn't technically need a `SALE_ITEM_ID` column as you could use a composite key of `SALE_ID,ARTICLE_ID` but I prefer to always have a table specific PK.